# Simplified javascript some function with almost the same code

Tags: javascript, function

Hei,  I'm working an app to simulate prices. I have a code like this.

```
  function max110(x) {
     if (x >= '1' && x <= '50') {
         var sum = 120 * x;
         hasil.value = 'Rp.' + parseFloat(sum * 1000);
     } else if (x >= '51' && x <= '100') {
         var sum = 115 * x;
         hasil.value = 'Rp.' + parseFloat(sum * 1000);
     } else if (x >= '101' && x <= '200') {
         var sum = 110 * x;
         hasil.value = 'Rp.' + parseFloat(sum * 1000);
     } else {
         hasil.value = 'error!';
     }
 }

 function max115(x) {
     if (x >= '1' && x <= '50') {
         var sum = 125 * x;
         hasil.value = 'Rp.' + parseFloat(sum * 1000);
     } else if (x >= '51' && x <= '100') {
         var sum = 120 * x;
         hasil.value = 'Rp.' + parseFloat(sum * 1000);
     } else if (x >= '101' && x <= '200') {
         var sum = 115 * x;
         hasil.value = 'Rp.' + parseFloat(sum * 1000);
     } else {
         hasil.value = 'error!';
     }
 }
```

And I still have some functions similar to that, it almost the same code I'm trying to make it simple, is it possible to make it in 1 function only?

Comment: is `x` a string or a number? and if a number, is it an integer? what is the expected range?

Comment: it's a string, should i need to parse it to integer?

Comment: i would use always numbers and it is unclear why you parse a numer. what do you want with it to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  function maxval(x,maxval) {
    if(x >= '1' && x <= '50'){
      var sum = (maxval+10)* x;
      hasil.value = 'Rp.'+parseFloat(sum*1000);
    }
     else if (x >= '51' && x <= '100'){
       var sum = (maxval+5)* x;
       hasil.value = 'Rp.'+parseFloat(sum*1000);
     }
     else if(x >= '101' && x <= '200'){
       var sum = (maxval)* x;
       hasil.value = 'Rp.'+parseFloat(sum*1000);
     }
     else{
       hasil.value = 'error!';
     }
  }
```

By the way i assumed that maxval increments by 5, Cant get you a better solution without getting more details about functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my implementation. I don't agree with how you're handling your integers, but it's your coding style. I pass in an object of choice that has all of the values that I want. You don't need the logic, just the values. I hope nobody gets mad that I monkeypatch `String`. I'm assuming that your variable `x` is a string.

```
String.prototype.isBetween = function(lower, upper){
  int = parseInt(this)
  return int >= parseInt(lower) && int <= parseInt(upper)
}

max110 = {0: 120, 1: 115, 2: 110}
max115 = {0: 125, 1: 120, 2: 115}
function max(x, values) {
  let sum
  hasil.value = ''
  if (x.isBetween('1', '50')) {
    sum = values['0'] * x
  } else if (x.isBetween('51', '100')) {
    sum = values['1'] * x
  } else if (x.isBetween('101', '200')) {
    sum = values['2'] * x
  } else {
    hasil.value = 'error'
  }
  hasil.value = hasil.value ? 'error' : 'Rp.'+parseFloat(sum*1000);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I just get started javascript since two or three month ago I don't understand what it is LOL :)

Comment: @naovalluthfi which part?

Comment: Almost all of it, I don't understand this code 'String.prototype.isBetween'

Comment: Oh, that's me taking a little shortcut and patching the string object. I basically made my own method for a string. adding something to an Object `prototype` is how to add your own methods to objects in ES5 syntax.

Comment: @naovalluthfi Haha, well, the `prototype` style of JavaScript method creation is being masked by the `class` syntax in ES6. It's always good to know your fundamentals, but you can get by for a surprisingly long time without ever doing something like what I showed you in my code. My code works though, right?

Comment: I even don't know what ES5 or ES6 is -,- Sorry I haven't tried yet

Answer (score 0):

```
function max(x, extra) {
  var sum_number = extra;
  if(x >= '1' && x <= '50'){
   sum_number += 120;
  }
  else if (x >= '51' && x <= '100'){
   sum_number += 115;
  }
  else if(x >= '101' && x <= '200'){
   sum_number += 110;
  }

  if(x < 1 && x > 200){
    hasil.value = 'error!';
  } else {
    hasil.value = 'Rp.'+parseFloat((sum_number) * x *1000);
  }
}
```

parameter `extra` can be 0 or 5 for function `max110` or `max115`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have two function which works the same way and returns the same with different values.

- The different values yould be stored in an array and you could use a single function for getting the index and then take the needed value out of the array with that index.
- So you need a better organisation of types of the variables, which if uses as number, it should be number and also for comparison, then it should be a number on both sides of the condition.
- Use a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), which does not alter a state of something, which is not given into the function.
- Use a check in the function for unwanted values and exit early with a first check at the lower border, in your case, it is zero and below, return `-1`, because that is not an index of an array (and it is usually used to denote, that no index is found, like with [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)).
- Then take the upper border for a check end exit early with a index value, no need for continuing `else if` structures.
- At the end return as well `-1` for not found index.

Together:

```js
function getValue(x, maxArray) {
    var index = getIndex(x);
    if (index in maxArray) {
        return 'Rp.' + maxArray[index] * x * 1000;
    }
    return 'error!';
}

function getIndex(x) {
    if (!x || x < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (x <= 50) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (x <= 100) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (x <= 200) {
        return 2;
    }
    return -1;
}

var max110 = [120, 115, 110],
    max115 = [125, 120, 115];

console.log(getValue(-1, max110));
console.log(getValue(10, max110));
console.log(getValue(10, max115));
```

Comment: I think I understand how it works, but I don't understand why -1?

Comment: it's just a definiton, because that value is not an index of an array. you could have a look here: [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: oh I know I know sorry, I just realized that when I read it again

Comment: But, `console.log('Rp.' + max110[index] * x * 1000);` can the `max110[index]` change automatically? Do you know what i mean?

Comment: you could move the complete logic into another function.

Comment: I see, so to create new prices (btw 120, 125 is prices) i just have to create new object and to get the value I just call `getValue()` function, is that right?

Comment: just call the function with the value and the array.

Comment: Got it. but i was wondering, is it ok to call a function before the function is defined?

Comment: function declaration gets hoisted.

Comment: So it's ok to do that?